# How to compute integral of a gaussian over a noncentered ball?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, functional-calculus

Let $\mathcal{B}(x,r)$ the ball of center $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and radius $r>0$ (so $\mathcal{B}(x,r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|y-x\| \leq r\}$, where all norms are $\ell^2$-norms).

I would like to express the following integral analytically:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{B}(x,r)} \exp\left(\frac{-\|y-\mu\|^2}{2r^2}\right)dy.
\end{equation}

For $\mu=x$, there is an easy analytic expression in the literature, using radial symmetry. However, it seems more complicated to me when $\mu \neq x$, and I did not find a lot of literature on this case.

Is it possible to express this analytically? How could I proceed?

Comment: Already when $x=\mu$ there is no analytical solution to my knowledge except a special function ... could you precise your claim?

Comment: yup, no analytical solution eve for centered gaussians, even in dimension 1... vote to close

Comment: For even $n$, there certainly is a simple analytical solution for $x=\mu $ due to the measure in spherical coordinates.

Comment: You are right. By analytical I meant express the solution in terms of erf function for instance (or other well known function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a real loss of generality, I can assume that $x=0$, $2r^2=1/π$, and I check
$$
J(x)=\int_{\vert y\vert\le 1} e^{-π\vert x-y\vert^2} dy=(G\ast\mathbf 1_{\mathbb B^n})(x),\qquad G(x)=e^{-π\vert x\vert^2}.
$$
The function $J$ is radial (if $A\in O(n)$, just calculate $J(Ax)$ by the change of variables $y=Az$) so that $J(x)=g(\vert x\vert)$ and thus
\begin{align}
g(r)
&=\int_{\vert y\vert\le 1} e^{-π\vert r e_1-y\vert^2} dy \\
&=\int_{\vert y_1\vert\le 1} \int_{\vert y'\vert^2\le 1-y_1^2}e^{-π(r-y_1)^2-π \vert y'\vert^2} dy\\
&=\int_{\vert t\vert\le 1}e^{-π(r-t)^2} \int_0^{\sqrt{1-t^2}} e^{-π \rho^2} \rho^{n-2} d\rho \vert\mathbb S^{n-2}\vert dt \\
&=\int_{\vert t\vert\le 1}e^{-π(r-t)^2} E_{n-1}(\sqrt{1-t^2})dt,
\end{align}
where $E_{n-1}$ is an Erf-type function. Not very explicit, but an integral in 1D.

Comment: The integral for $E$ actually leads to the incomplete gamma function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-Pi+r%5E2%5D+r%5E%28n+-+1%29%2C+%7Br%2C+0%2C+x%7D%2C+Assumptions+-%3E+%7Bn+%3E+1%2C+x+%3E+0%7D%5D